# Arrow rain(How can express the shaking effect when an arrow is hit?)

Tags: particles

[kill particles ver](https://vimeo.com/368493112)

[before Kill Particle](https://vimeo.com/368493434)

I want to add a trembling effect when the arrow hits.
However, kill particles can stop when they are closed on an object, but they don't have a trembling effect.

[3d max tuto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcefk6V6yjM)

I want to know how to give a trembling effect while fixing like this 3DS Max tutorial.

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/t/arrow-rain-how-can-express-the-shaking-effect-when-an-arrow-is-hit/1187301

Answer (score 1):

Wow that would be neat to see. Breaking it down you will first have to detect when the arrow particle collides, then start the tremble. To make the tremble you can do it several ways, tremble the whole arrow and target, rig the arrow with a bone, use key shapes, or modify the transform rotation of the arrow.

I don't know what method you wish to use, but in all the animation sequence for the arrow particle needs to be triggered after the collision is detected. You can try using the "Action" constraint. If that doesn't work the only thing I can think of is a script, which will probably be only about 6 lines of code, but what code is currently beyond me. I hope the action constraint will do it for you.